# Create Pandas frequency of item occurrences along with proportion in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, frequency, proportions

I want to get both a frequency and a percentage of a particular value of a df column. Say I have a df with (col1, col2 , col3, PhoneService, Churn) 'PhoneService' column has values of Yes or No. I want to get both the counts and the percentage of Yes/No values for in the df.

I have tried this, which gives me the number of instances, but I want these as a count and percentage of the total number of values in the df.

```
df_telco.groupby("PhoneService")["Churn"].value_counts()

((df_telco.groupby("PhoneService")["Churn"].value_counts(normalize=True))*100).round(2).astype(str) + ' %'
```

It gives me the output in 2 different tables.

| PhoneService | Churn | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No | No | 512 |
|  | Yes | 170 |
| Yes | No | 4662 |
|  | Yes | 1699 |

| PhoneService | Churn | proportion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No | No | 75.07 % |
|  | Yes | 24.93 % |
| Yes | No | 73.29 % |
|  | Yes | 26.71 % |

But I want them in the same output with an additional column for proportion in %:

| PhoneService | Churn | count | proportion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No | No | 512 | 75.07 % |
|  | Yes | 170 | 24.93 % |
| Yes | No | 4662 | 73.29 % |
|  | Yes | 1699 | 26.71 % |

Is there any way to show them in single output?

Comment: You can simply `concat` those two outputs - the output from a `value_counts` is a pandas Series object.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `concat` the two outputs as each of the `value_counts()` returns a `Series` with the same index -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aaabbb'), 'B': list('cdcdcd'), 'C': list(range(6)), 'D': list('xxxxyy')})
grouped_df = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['D'].value_counts()
grouped_pc_df = ((df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['D'].value_counts(normalize=True))*100).round(2).astype(str) + ' %'
grouped_final_df = pd.concat([grouped_df, grouped_pc_df], axis=1)
grouped_final_df.columns = ['num', 'pc']
grouped_final_df

#       num       pc
#A B D              
#a c x    2  100.0 %
#  d x    1  100.0 %
#b c y    1  100.0 %
#  d x    1   50.0 %
#    y    1   50.0 %
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for!